# Check if each string (all of them) on a list is a substring in at least one of the strings in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, substring, subset

I am having a hard time trying to check if all of the strings in a python list are a subset of any string in another Python list.

Example:
I want to check if each string(all of them) of `list1` is in at least one of the strings in the `list2` and if it is, do something.

```
list1 = ['tomato', 'onions','egg']
list2 = ['Two tomatos', 'two onions','two eggs','salsa']
```

In this example for instance it would return `True`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use generator expressions combined with `any`/`all` functions:

```
>>> list1 = ['tomato', 'onions','egg']
>>> list2 = ['Two tomatos', 'two onions','two eggs','salsa']
>>> all(any(i in j for j in list2) for i in list1)
True
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I was using all() but did not combine that with any()
Thank you sir!

Comment: In case you've missed the reasoning; you want **all** of the values in `list1` to match **any** one of the values in `list2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a single command using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), `any`, and `all`.

```py
list1 = ['tomato', 'onions','egg']
list2 = ['Two tomatos', 'two onions','two eggs','salsa']
result = all([any([keyword in string for string in list2]) for keyword in list1])
```

The first list comprehension `[keyword in string for string in list2]`checks that a keyword is at least present in all strings of `list2` and produces a list of boolean. We use any to determine if any result was `True`.

The second list comprehension is built on top of the first list comprehension `[any([keyword in string for string in list2]) for keyword in list1]` and checks that all keywords were are least present in all the string of `list2`. We use `all` to check that all results are `True`.

As @Selcuk mentioned, you can do it more efficiently using [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289): the syntax is really is really close to list comprehensions:

```py
result = all(any(keyword in string for string in list2) for keyword in list1)
```

Answer (score -2):

You could go through the lists and execute something if it meets the condition that the word from list 1 exists in some element of list 2, for example:

```
list1 = ['tomato', 'onions','egg']
list2 = ['Two tomatos', 'two onions','two eggs','salsa']
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i in j:
            print("something to ", i, " and ", j)
```